# Continuity of a function defined as an (improper?) indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following problem dealing with Lebesgue integrals.

> Let $f$ be a (general) Lebesgue integrable function over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $F: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be given by $F(x):= \int^{x}_{-\infty}f$. Prove $F$ is continuous. Give an example of a function $f$ such that $F$ is not Lipschitz.

I'm not sure how to proceed, but here's what I've tried. I'm using the spoiler blockquotes so as not to clutter the question; please let me know if I should change this! Thanks in advance for any hints or solutions.

> Note that $F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f \cdot \chi_{(-\infty, x]}$, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space, $F$ is continuous if and only if $F(x_n) \rightarrow F(x)$, for all sequences $\{x_n\}$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow x$. I was hoping to be able to appeal to some convergence theorem at this point, since I have $f \cdot \chi_{(-\infty, x_n]} \rightarrow f \cdot \chi_{(-\infty, x]}$, for any sequence converging to $x$, but I'm not sure which one to use, if any.

Comment: Domination is good.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, thanks for replying! Is your suggestion to dominate each  $f \cdot \chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}$ by $f$? If so, how can I show that $f$ satsifies the required hypothesis to dominate $f \cdot \chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}$? In particular, how do I know that $f \geq 0$? Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Dominate by $\lvert f\rvert$. Since $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable, so is $\lvert f\rvert$.

Comment: Oh, duh! What an easy fix, I almost regret having asked! Thank you!